# How to avoid Reflection Exception in Laravel's project and what are the causes which produce it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have made a project named `my-school` using Laravel. Everything works fine, except when I run my project using XAMPP.
I'm then using this url: `localhost/my-school/public/`.

Here's the raised exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
'Class MySchool\Http\Kernel does not exist' in
E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:776
Stack trace: #0
E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(776):
ReflectionClass->__construct('MySchool\\Http\\K...') #1
E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(656):
Illuminate\Container\Container->build('MySchool\\Http\\K...', Array)
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(613):
Illuminate\Container\Container->make('MySchool\\Http\\K...', Array) #3
E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(229):
Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('MySchool\\Http\\K...', Array)
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(773):
Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{clo in
E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
on line 776
```

And here is my **composer.json** file content:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Can somebody please help me finding an issue with my project?

Comment: can you attach composer's content in the question? In order to review it

Comment: Sir please check my updated question... I have added my composer.json file content... Please tell me if anything more you need... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the composer autoload's value:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

This means that your namespace for all classes inside of `app\ folder` should be start with 'App\' as name. In your case, the error states:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Class MySchool\Http\Kernel does not exist'

`MySchool\Http\Kernel` will never be loaded because it does not exist. Instead, your composer demands the following structure:

```
Class App\Http\Kernel
```

See the difference? then, try to rename the app as follow:

```
php artisan app:name MySchool
```

At that way, all classes will route as MySchool as I think you want.

Comment: Thanks alot sir but now i am getting this error as i put this line this into my browser "localhost/my-school/public/". 
Warning: require(E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xampp\htdocs\my-school\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Comment: ok thanks alot once again. It was my bad. Please tell me as do i need to change all the namespaces by going into each and every .php file or is there anything handy to replace all existing namespaces with the required one?

Comment: Thanks alot Sir as i sorted it out. I was updating composer in the root folder rather than installing it. After fresh composer installation there. I see no more issues. Thanks once again.

Comment: Good, glad to help you!

Comment: I hope we will assist each other in the future as well. Thanks a bunch.